# Transform/Animate View in Activity1 to View in Activity2

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation, android-imageview

I have two `ImageViews` which contain the same image. The `Views` are located in two different `Activities`. I want an Animation which - for the user - transforms the Image1 to Image2.

Is it possible to create a `Transformation` or `Animation` which resizes and repositions the `ImageView` from Activity1 to the location and size of the `ImageView` of Acitivity2?

Hope I made my point somewhat clear...

Thanks!

Ron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No (if I understand your question correctly). Activities are independent. All you can do is pass the attributes (like size, bitmap etc) from first ImageView and apply to second one. Or merge these two activities in one.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com hey man may i know how to merge two activities in one..it will be really great help if you reply..thanks in adv

Comment: this not just "merge". I rather meant you should create activity combining UI and logic from these two (perhaps using fragments). That would let you to do some more fancy UI transitions withing activity elements

Answer (score 1):

You could only achieve what you describe with very carefully timed custom activity transitions combined with animations for the ImageViews. If is possible to create your own Activity transitions, see [`Activity.overridePendingTransition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29). See also this [official guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html) for general info on creating Animations.

If possible, consider re-designing so you can transition between Fragments within the same activity, or with a ViewSwitcher e.g.:

```
viewSwitcher.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.in_animation);
viewSwitcher.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out_animation);
viewSwitcher.showNext();
```